# Error when importing models into test.py file, django

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

I'm trying to create a test.py file for some of my database methods in a current django project. I need to import my models.py file, but the import statement I'm using below (which follows the official Django example) is causing an error. Both test.py and models.py are already in appFolder, so is that the issue?

```
from appFolder.models import Class1,Class2,Class3
```

Using only 'import models' didn't work when I ran it earlier. How can I resolve this? (I have also been running the file with the command './manage.py test' if that's relevant)

Comment: Did you try `from .models import Class1...` version? If they are inside the same folder you can use a relative import. We can share a better answer if you can add a stack trace. Usually, we need the stack trace to identify the problem better.

Comment: That seemed to work! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have files in the same folder, you can use relative imports. Here is the example code:

```
from .models import Class1
```

There might be several problems but possibly you have missed the app inside the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your settings file. That is a common mistake but relative imports work fine if you can manually trigger the tests.